# BadRequest on modified Spring Oauth2 example royclarkson github

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have based on the following example in order to create a secure REST Api: https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth

The problem is that when I try to get the token I always get Bad Credentials error.

The code is equal, so my guess is that I'm not doing the access token query properly. Following is my curl:

```
C:\Users\Javier\Desktop\curl\bin>curl -X POST -vu clientapp:123456 http://localhost:8080/wombee/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=javi&username=javi&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=123456&client_id=clientapp"
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'clientapp'
> POST /wombee/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50YXBwOjEyMzQ1Ng==
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.1
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Length: 107
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 107 out of 107 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Petición incorrecta
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Fri, 25 Mar 2016 10:52:01 GMT
< Connection: close
<
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Bad credentials"}* Closing connection 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, in `CustomUserDetailsService` I had `getPassword` method override with a null, that was my problem.